# Sql combining tables from items to make a package

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble with this one and I just need a little help

I have 2 tables

```
temp_id uoc description
305202  AYM HtSeats
305202  BCM Leather
305202  BJB Navigation
305202  BLA PwrSeat
276722  8   Pwr Driver Seat
276722  43  Dual Factory Air
276722  9   w/o Power Windows/Locks
276722  ADM AlloyWhl
276722  AMM Cruise
276722  ATP BackupCam
276722  BJB Navigation
276722  BKM PwrLks
276722  BLA PwrSeat
276722  BMA PwrWind
276722  BNP RearAir

temp_id bbra1   bbra2   bbra3
305202  AYM BLA 
305202  BCM BLA AYM
276722  ADM ATP 
276722  BKM BNP BMA
```

and I need to combine them to make this one

```
temp_id uoc description
305202  AYM/BLA HtSeats/PwrSeat
305202  BCM/BLA/AYM Leather/PwrSeat/HtSeats
276722  ADM/ATP AlloyWhl/BackupCam
276722  BKM/BNP/BMA PwrLks/RearAir/PwrWind
```

Any help would be nice thank you

Comment: Do you have 2 or 3 fields in the first table `temp_id uoc description`?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?  SQL Server, MySQL, etc?

Comment: 3 fields temp_id uoc description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see why this caused trouble.  The solution is not entirely obvious.  The query below uses three joins, one for each of the columns.

It then concatenates the columns together, taking care to avoid problems with `NULL` values.

```
select t.temp_id,
       (case when t.bbra3 is not null then concat(t.bbra1, '/', t.bbra2, '/', t.bbra3)
             when t.bbra2 is not null then concat(t.bbra1, '/', t.bbra2)
             else t.bbra1
        end) as uoc,
       (case when t.bbra3 is not null then concat(t1.description, '/', t2.description, '/', t3.description)
             when t.bbra2 is not null then concat(t1.description, '/', t2.description)
             else t1.description
        end) as description
from table2 t
     table1 t1 left outer join
     on t1.uoc = t.bbra1 and t1.temp_id = t.temp_id left outer join
     table1 t2 
     on t2.uoc = t.bbra2 and t2.temp_id = t.temp_id left outer join
     table3 t3 
     on t3.uoc = t.bbra3 and t3.temp_id = t.temp_id;
```

This version uses SQL standards throughout.  In particular, it uses `concat()`.  However, not all databases use `concat()` for string concatenation, so you might need to infix operators like `+` or `||`.

Comment: @user2615302 . . . I don't understand your comment.  The description is coming from `table1`.  There are three joins, one for each `bbra` code.  They are then concatenated the same way as the uoc.